# loading a multi-page template with jQuery mobile ajax navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

By default, if you use ajax navigation of jQuery Mobile for loading a multi-page template html file, it doesn't work and just first page loads.

One method is using `rel="external"`, but it doesn't look well in a mobile phone or a tablet... (It should have animation!)

Isn't there any better way? How to completely load a multi-page template html with jQuery Mobile ajax navigation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can programmatically load pages into the DOM by using

```
pageContainerElement.page({ domCache: true });
```

The drawback of DOM caching is that the DOM can get very large, resulting in slowdowns and memory issues on some devices. If you enable DOM caching, take care to manage the DOM yourself and test thoroughly on a range of devices.

Here's the link: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-cache.html

**UPDATE 1**

You would put that code in a separate file, i.e. `custom-code.js` and put it in your header after you load jQuery but BEFORE you load jQuery Mobile.

So if your page container looks like this:

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a" data-dom-cache="false" class="page blog-post">
```

You would put `div.page({ domCache: true });` and then in the head of all of the pages where you pull in jQuery and jQuery mobile, it would look like this:

```
// Pull in jQuery
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
// Pull in your custom jQuery Mobile rules/scripts
<script src="../path/to-file/custom-code.js"></script>
// Pull in jQuery Mobile
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

**UPDATE 2**

The code above will cache that particular page. If you want to load ALL pages into the DOM, inside of the custom-code.js file, place this code and specify separately (one instance for each page) each page that you want to load into the DOM:

```
$.mobile.loadPage( pageUrl, { showLoadMsg: false } );
```

> Prefetching pages naturally creates additional HTTP requests and uses
>   bandwidth, so it's wise to use this feature only in situations where
>   it's highly likely that the prefetched page will be visited.

Also, if you want to pre-fetch all of the pages linked to on the current page, just add `data-prefetch` to the link.

For example:

```
<a href="page_2.html" data-prefetch>Link to other page</a>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understand your code. Where should I put that code?

Comment: And will it loads other `data-role="page"` divs from second page as well?

Comment: But how that code forces jQuery Mobile to load other `data-role="pages"` from second page??

Comment: I'm sorry, but I didn't understand... your code prefetchs the page, that's ok, but how it tells jQuery Mobile to load a multi-page template?

Comment: Explain what you mean by "load a multi-page template."

Comment: a page that has more than one `<div data-role="page">...</div>` and can be navigated by `<a href="#page_name">Go to page 2</a>`.

Comment: If you prefetch a page, it's going to prefetch all of the `<div data-role="page">...</div>` in that file.  You should read up on the jQuery Mobile docs. http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/

Comment: I have read some parts of jQuery Mobile docs, but I didn't see anything about this. can you tell me the exact link?

Answer (score 1):

By default, jQuery mobile doesn't load all pages of a multi-page template. But there is [a plugin](https://github.com/ToddThomson/jQuery-Mobile-Subpage-Widget) for jQuery Mobile which allows you to load a multi-page template with ajax navigation.

[Check out jQuery-Mobile-Subpage-Widget here.](https://github.com/ToddThomson/jQuery-Mobile-Subpage-Widget)